# PHP Custom Session Name

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I've been coding a website for a long time, but never used the `session_name()` function built in PHP to set a custom session name instead of the default (PHPSESSID).

I've had a login page that redirects you to another file after a successful login. In that file, I was basically checking `isset($_SESSION)` if I wasn't set I redirect to the login page. Otherwise, I say `Hello $_SESSION["Username"]`.

I've recently decided to use the `session_name` and set a custom name. However, now the script in the second file (checking if `$_SESSION` was set) always says it's not set. I just changed the session name.

Then I searched around on Google and have seen that I need to do again `sesssion_name()` and `session_start()` in the second file to get access to the username.

**TL;DR**

Do I always need to do `session_name()` and `session_start()` on every file I want to get access to the data of my session with a custom session name?

*I can clarify some things if it's unclear; might not be easy to understand.*

Comment: You always need to do `session_start()` on every page that needs access  to the session vars whether you use session name or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll either need to run `session_name()` on every file that needs access to the custom session, store the logic in a separate include file which is included within all relevant files, or change PHP's default session name via the `session.name` [configuration value](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.name).

Without specifying `session_name()` in each case, PHP won't know that you want it to use a different name, and instead, default to the value from `session.name`.